# Basic Concept of Chatbot using Wit.ai

Tags: node.js, chatbot, wit.ai

I am trying to create a chatbot application where user can create their own bot like [Botengine](https://www.botengine.ai/). After going through  google I saw I need some NLP api to process user's query. As per wit.ai [basic example](https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart) I can set and get data. Now I am confused, How I am going to create a botengine?

So as far I understand the flow, Here is an example for pizza delivery:-

1. User will enter a welcome message i.e - Hi, Hello ...
2. Welcome reply will be saved by bot owner in my database.
3. User will enter some query, then I will hit wit.ai API to process that query. Example :- Users query is "What kind of pizza's available in your store" and wit.ai will respond with the details of intent "pizza_type"
4. Then I will search for the intent return by wit in my database.

So, is that the right flow to create a chatbot? Am I in the right direction? Could anyone give me some link or some example so I can go through it. I want to create this application using nodejs. I have also found some example in [node-wit](https://github.com/wit-ai/node-wit), but can't find how I will implement this.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very generic. 

Maybe consider adding smaller separate questions instead of this, or describe the specifications of your chatbot more thoroughly.

Some things to consider are: 
1) Will your chatbot run on some platform? (eg: Facebook, WeChat, Viber etc)
2) Maybe you should first create a static chatbot and then move on to a dynamic one (create firstly a Chatbot that does one thing and then create a full-fledged "BotEngine")

You can also check the getting started part of Messenger's Platform's documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/

Comment: Yes my question should be for a module not the whole thing. Basically I want to create a chatbot for my own site. I need a basic concept how would I get user data and return the answer.

Comment: Then restate your question 

Answer (score 1):

What you need is webhook. You need to call different API's based on the user intent. I believe you can distinguish between different intents using parameters available in request. Check this out - [Creating nodejs webhook for dialogflow](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/creating-nodejs-webhook-for-dialogflow-2b050f76cd75)

Comment: Thanks's for the answer. As I have stated the flow, you have done like that. But can you tell me how I can reply with user details. Like  - User has provided their name and bot will reply with the name like "Hi {{name}}"?